# Why ngSwitch infinitely renders template?

Tags: angular

I have the following temaplate with switch:

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="block.type">
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'block'">
        <div class="requestDocumentBlock">
            <div>
                <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="children; context: { block: block }"></ng-container>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Field --->

    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'field'">
        <app-request-document-field [fieldDefinition]="block"></app-request-document-field>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Custom --->

    <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
        <app-request-document-field
            [fieldDefinition]="block"
            *ngFor="let block of documentCustomBlock?.getVisibleControls()"
        ></app-request-document-field>
        <button (click)="setDocument()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Задать документ</button>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

So, problem is in this part of code:

```
<app-request-document-field
            [fieldDefinition]="block"
            *ngFor="let block of documentCustomBlock?.getVisibleControls()"
        ></app-request-document-field>
```

By default `documentCustomBlock?.getVisibleControls()` is empty array. When data comes it starts to render whole template infinitely.

I can not get why?

**UPDATE:**

**Component is:**

```
public documentCustomBlock: DocumentCustomBlock;
this.dialog
            .open(DialogLoadDocumentComponent, dialogConfig)
            .afterClosed()
            .subscribe((documentCustomBlock: DocumentCustomBlock) => {
                  this.documentCustomBlock = documentCustomBlock;
                    this.changeDetection.detectChanges();
 });
```

**Template is:**

```
<app-request-document-field
 [fieldDefinition]="block"
 *ngFor="let block of documentCustomBlock?.getVisibleControls()"></app-request-document-field>
```

Comment: functions are called on every application `tick`, which means your `*ngFor` is probably rerendering a lot. It would be easier to store the result of `getVisibleControls()` in your component and then iterate over it in the template

Comment: Now I do this. Look at my question again, I have added changes

Comment: Same problem still, functions are called also when change detection is set to `onPush` because angular cannot be sure if they lead to the same object reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible answers:

This one would try to take only one observable emit which would update data

```
public documentCustomBlock: DocumentCustomBlock;
this.dialog
            .open(DialogLoadDocumentComponent, dialogConfig)
            .afterClosed()
            .pipe(
                take(1)
            )
            .subscribe((documentCustomBlock: DocumentCustomBlock) => {
                  this.documentCustomBlock = documentCustomBlock;
                    this.changeDetection.detectChanges();
 });
```

Or

This one would use async pipe which would automatically resolve

```
public documentCustomBlock: DocumentCustomBlock = this.dialog
    .open(DialogLoadDocumentComponent, dialogConfig)
    .afterClosed();


<app-request-document-field
    [fieldDefinition]="block"
*ngFor="let block of documentCustomBlock?.getVisibleControls() | async"
    ></app-request-document-field>
```